# Calendar roll operation doesn't provide me with the correct output

Tags: java, calendar

We are using Calendar.[roll](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/site/images/recursos/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#roll(int,%20int)) to either move the dates up or down. The javadoc mentions that the larger fields are not modified (i.e. if we move the date by 5 to the left starting on the first day of the month, unfortunately the calendar.getTime() doesn't get me a value from the previous month). The month value remains unchanged, how do I change this behavior. I really would like to move the date value as appropriate. (e.g. If I moved 5 days to the left on Aug 1st, 2010 - I would want to see Jun 27th, 2010 instead of Aug 27th, 2010). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Calendar.add` with a negative `amount`.

Answer (score 8):

You will need to use [`add(Calendar.DATE, -5)` method from `Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int))  because of roll rule check.

**`roll` method is described as :**

> Add to `field` a signed amount without
>   changing larger fields. A negative
>   roll amount means to subtract from
>   field without changing larger fields.
>
> Example: Consider a `GregorianCalendar`
>   originally set to August 31, 1999.
>   Calling `roll(Calendar.MONTH, 8)` sets
>   the calendar to April 30, 1999. Using
>   a GregorianCalendar, the `DAY_OF_MONTH`
>   field cannot be 31 in the month April.
>   `DAY_OF_MONTH` is set to the closest
>   possible value, 30. The `YEAR` field
>   maintains the value of 1999 because it
>   is a larger field than `MONTH`.
>
> Example: Consider a `GregorianCalendar`
>   originally set to Sunday June 6, 1999.
>   Calling `roll(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH,
>   -1)` sets the calendar to Tuesday June 1, 1999, whereas calling
>   `add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -1)` sets
>   the calendar to Sunday May 30, 1999.
>   This is because the roll rule imposes
>   an additional constraint: The `MONTH`
>   must not change when the `WEEK_OF_MONTH`
>   is rolled. Taken together with add
>   rule 1, the resultant date must be
>   between Tuesday June 1 and Saturday
>   June 5. According to add rule 2, the
>   `DAY_OF_WEEK`, an invariant when
>   changing the `WEEK_OF_MONTH`, is set to
>   Tuesday, the closest possible value to
>   Sunday (where Sunday is the first day
>   of the week).

Comment: This explanation help me lot.